# Apache: configuring virtual hosts

Tags: apache2

I was having some trouble in configuring virtual hosts in Apache 2.2.3 CentOS, 
I have the following configuration:

httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost mydomain.site.ch

<VirtualHost mydomain.site.ch>
    ServerName mydomain.site.ch
    DocumentRoot /home/django_www/hello
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
x.y.z.89        mydomain.site.ch
```

I need to match all the requests that comes to this server with the second VirtualHost entry  except the one coming with this domain name "mydomain.site.ch" .
But the result: with this configuration i get all the requests handled by the first VirtualHost entry.. (the configuration syntax is OK!) Any ideas in how to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change it in this way:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.site.ch
    DocumentRoot /home/django_www/hello
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django_www/hello/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/django_www/hello>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /home/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If this will not help then try next:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost x.y.z.89:80>
    ServerName mydomain.site.ch
    DocumentRoot /home/django_www/hello
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django_www/hello/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/django_www/hello>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /home/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE - `/etc/hosts`**

If you want to serve the requests from outside with your localhost VirtualHost, you'll might have to set it explicitly in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
x.y.z.89     localhost
x.y.z.89     mydomain.site.ch
```

Then try to open in browser:

`http://mydomain.site.ch` and `http://x.y.z.89/`

Comment: getting crazy with this httpd.conf, doesn't want to work (i've tried a lot of different configurations...)!!!

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? E.g. the settings for directories `/var/www/html` and `/home/django_www/html` inside the settings for your VirtualHosts.

Comment: the folder "/var/www/html" contains only static html pages with an index.html file.  "/home/django_www/hello" contains a Django project created using "django-admin.py startproject hello"..(just that, i've not edited it.)

Comment: I mean <Directory> node inside <VirtualHost> - look at my edits in the answer.

Comment: i don't use any directory tag within the VIrtualHost

Comment: ..but now , i'm going to try your solution.

Comment: already changed my VirtualHost file... it should be some serious problem with my server.. (i can neither format it! It's one of the servers of my university..)